# addEventListener mouseenter not

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I would like to find out how can I go (on click) through every element with class children. If children element has additional class selected I would like to set counter to += 1.

After All I have plan to print message on same click: You have either 0,1,2,3 elements selected with class .SELECTED

Can you help me on that?

```js
const children = document.querySelectorAll('.children');
const selected = document.getElementsByClassName('selected');
const button = document.getElementById('bttn');
let counter = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {

    children[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
        if (children[i].classList.contains('selected')) {
            children[i].classList.remove('selected')
        } else {
            children[i].classList.add('selected')
        }

        button.addEventListener('click', () => {
            for (u = 0; u < children[i]; u++) {
                if (children[i].classList == 'selected') {
                    counter++;
                }
            }
            console.log(counter);
        })

    })

}
```

```css
#div {
            display: inline-flex;
            flex-direction: column;
        }

        .children {
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .selected {
            background-color: royalblue;
        }
```

```html
<div id="div">
        <span class='children selected'>children1</span>
        <span class='children'>children2</span>
        <span class='children'>children3</span>
    </div>
    <p><input id="bttn" type='button' value='klik'></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make your loops a little easier to read using a `forEach` loop and referencing objects with `event.target`. Rather than testing to see if an element contains a class just to add/remove it, use `classList.toggle()`.

```
e.target.classList.toggle('selected');
```

To get the total number of `children` with class `selected` you can simply do this one liner:

```
counter = document.querySelectorAll('.children.selected').length
```

```js
const children = document.querySelectorAll('.children');
const selected = document.getElementsByClassName('selected');
const button = document.getElementById('bttn');
let counter = 0;
children.forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.target.classList.toggle('selected');
  })
})
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  counter = document.querySelectorAll('.children.selected').length;
  console.log(counter);
})
```

```css
#div {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.children {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.selected {
  background-color: royalblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="div">
  <span class='children selected'>children1</span>
  <span class='children'>children2</span>
  <span class='children'>children3</span>
</div>
<p><input id="bttn" type='button' value='klik'></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the following more or less does what you are hoping to accomplish(?). The total reported should vary between 0 and max number of `.children` elements - the counter therefore needs to be reset when the button is clicked and the count re-calculated.

```js
/*
  initial variables for counter, 
  click event and class names
*/
let counter=0;
let pcn='children';
let cn='selected';
let evt='click';

/*
  shorthand utility methods
*/
const d=document;
const qa=(n,e)=>n.querySelectorAll(e);
const q=(n,e)=>n.querySelector(e);


/*
  Find all nodes with class `children`
  and iterate through collection. 
  Add a `click` handler to each and 
  toggle the active class `selected`
  when clicked.

  Increase the counter accordingly.
*/
let col=qa(d, '.' + pcn );
    col.forEach( n=>{
      n.addEventListener(evt,e=>{
        n.classList.toggle( cn );
        counter += n.classList.contains( cn ) ? 1 : 0;
      });
    });
    
        
/*
  Assign a `click` evnt handler to each button ( assumed more than one )
  - reset the counter when clicked and restart the counter.
*/
qa(d,'input[type="button"]').forEach(n=>{
  n.addEventListener(evt,e=>{
    counter=0;
    col.forEach( c=>{
      if( c.classList.contains( cn ) )counter++;
    });
    console.info( counter );
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.children {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.selected {
  background-color: royalblue;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class='children selected'>children1</span>
  <span class='children'>children2</span>
  <span class='children'>children3</span>
</div>
<input type='button' value='klik' />
```